# Como excluir um conteúdo HTML gerado através do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-4

Boa tarde, amigos.

Estou com o seguinte problema:
No meu formulário é possível que o usuário insira novos inputs (através de um botão) para preencher mais dados, o processo que realizei foi uma adição de conteúdo através do innerHTML e appendChild.

A imagem abaixo é o design que utilizei, a um botão "adicionar" que insere um novo input com todas características do input anterior (id, name, class, etc), acrescentando apenas um botão de "remover".

Este botão de remover deve remover exatamente o mesmo input que adicionou e ai que esta a minha dificuldade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
/* Código Js que utilizo para adicionar o input e o botão "remover": */

function addDepartamento(divName) {
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

   newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-sm-8"><label  for="descricaoDepartamento">Descrição do Departamento</label><input type="text"  id="descricaoDepartamento" name="descricaoDepartamento" class="form-control" placeholder="">  </div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><button type="button" style="margin-top: 29px;"  class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" onclick="rmvDepartamento()">Remover  Departamento</button></div><hr style="width:100%; border-color: black;">';

   document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
addDepartamento('linhaDepartamento');
```

```html
<!-- Código do botão adicionar -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
    <label for="descricaoDepartamento">Descrição do Departamento</label>
    <input type="text" id="descricaoDepartamento" name="descricaoDepartamento" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <button type="button" style="margin-top: 29px;" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" onclick="addDepartamento('linhaDepartamento')">Adicionar Departamento</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-12" id="linhaDepartamento"></div>
</div>
```

Pesquisei em alguns lugares e acredito que será necessário realizar um incremento para cada adição de conteúdo gerado pelo botão "adicionar", mas como eu posso identificar isso para que o remover exclua a div correta?

Comment: Em vez de usar `onclick="rmvDepartamento()"`, use _event listener_ para capturar o click no botão e remova a div principal `.row` onde ele está, usando `.closest(".row").remove()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente substituir a função `rmvDepartamento()` dentro do seu `onclick` para `parentNode.parentNode.remove()`, como por exemplo:

```js
/* Código Js que utilizo para adicionar o input e o botão "remover": */

function addDepartamento(divName) {
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

   newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-sm-8"><label  for="descricaoDepartamento">Descrição do Departamento</label><input type="text"  id="descricaoDepartamento" name="descricaoDepartamento" class="form-control" placeholder="">  </div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><button type="button" style="margin-top: 29px;"  class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" onclick="parentNode.parentNode.remove()">Remover  Departamento</button></div><hr style="width:100%; border-color: black;">';

   document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
addDepartamento('linhaDepartamento');
```

```html
<!-- Código do botão adicionar -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
    <label for="descricaoDepartamento">Descrição do Departamento</label>
    <input type="text" id="descricaoDepartamento" name="descricaoDepartamento" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <button type="button" style="margin-top: 29px;" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" onclick="addDepartamento('linhaDepartamento')">Adicionar Departamento</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-12" id="linhaDepartamento"></div>
</div>
```